# SCP File from local to Heroku Server

Tags: linux, heroku, scp

I'd like to copy my config.yml file from my local django app directory to my heroku server, but I'm not sure how to get the user@host.com format for heroku.

I've tried running 'heroku run bash'

```
scp  /home/user/app/config.yml
```

I'm not sure how I can get it in the

```
scp user@myhost.com:/home/user/dir1/file.txt user@myhost.com:/home/user/dir2'
```

format

Answer (score 35):

As @tamas7 said it's firewalled, but your local machine is probably also firewalled. So unless you have a private server with SSH accessible from the Internet, you won't be able to scp.

I'm personally using [transfer.sh](https://transfer.sh/) free and [open source](https://github.com/dutchcoders/transfer.sh) service.

Upload your `config.yml` to it:

```
$ curl --upload-file ./config.yml https://transfer.sh/
https://transfer.sh/66nb8/config.yml
```

Then download it back from wherever you want:

```
$ wget https://transfer.sh/66nb8/config.yml
```

Comment: Really upload config files unencrypted?

Comment: @Michael, yes you can use gpg if you want, but that was not the OP question and I tried to keep it straightforward.
Feel free to add a complement answer to this one if you think it's useful.

Comment: Neat trick, really useful for what I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: If you want to encrypt it you can upload it using:

`cat <file_name> | gpg -ac -o- | curl -X PUT -T "-" https://transfer.sh/<file_name>.gpg`

And download it using:

`curl https://transfer.sh/<hash>/<file_name>.gpg | gpg -o- > <file_name>`

Comment: Is this safe I upload my .env file to transfer.sh ..?

Comment: Depends what you mean by safe @GofyandKitty, but you can always encrypt it

Comment: transfer.sh does not seem to work right now. https://file.io seems to be an alternative

Answer (score 7):

According to http://www.evans.io/posts/heroku-survival-guide/ incoming connections are firewalled off. In this case you need to approach your local machine from the Heroku server.

```
heroku run bash
scp user@mylocalmachine:/home/user/dir/file.txt .
```

Comment: `user@mylocalmachine` - do I need an ip address? How do I tell it where my local machine is?

Comment: "mylocalmachine" is the IP and "user" is the user that you are logging in to your server

Comment: How do i put user@mylocalmachine using my laptop local machine? :D

Comment: Google : Get my IP 

copy your IP and replace ```mylocalmiachine``` by this IP , ```user``` by your laptop username

Comment: By i got ```kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host``` ERROR

Answer (score 3):

This is a bit late to answer this question, but I use services like `localtunnel` - https://localtunnel.github.io/www/ to copy files from local machine to heroku.

First, run a python HTTP server in the directory where the file is located.

```
cd /path/to/file
python3 -m http.server
```

This starts a server in port 8000. Configure localtunnel to connect to that port.

```
lt -s mylocal -p 8000
```

Now from your heroku machine, you can fetch the file via curl.

```
curl -XGET http://mylocal.localtunnel.me/myfile.txt > myfile.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also use a service like https://ngrok.com/ to open up a TCP tunnel into your local machine.

You will need to enable Remote Login as in [simlmx answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64526041/14572290).

On your local machine open the TCP tunnel just like this:

```
$ ngrok tcp 22
```

And then, on the Heroku console, just use SCP with the PORT and HOST that Ngrok provided.

```
$ scp -P [PORT] username@[HOST]:~/path/to/file.ext .
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to download your entire repo, for example to recover an app that you no longer have locally, use `heroku git:clone -a myapp`. [Docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git-clone-heroku-app).

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on [tamas7's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27801278/1067132):

You can connect to your computer from the heroku server.

If your computer is behind a router, you'll also need to forward the connection to your computer.

### 1. You computer must accept `ssh` connections

On my mac it was as simple as enabling it in the `Preferences / Sharing` panel.
[image]

### 2. Your router needs to forward the connection to your computer.

Go to your router's settings page in your browser (typically `192.168.0.1` but varies depending on the router). Find the port forwarding section and forward some port to your computer on port `22`.

This is how it looked on my tp-link:
[image]

Here I am making sure that port `22000` is forwarded to my computer (`192.168.0.110`) on port `22`.

### 3. Find your external IP

Simply google "what is my IP".

### 4. Scp your file from heroku

```sh
heroku run bash
scp -P 22000 your_user@your_external_IP:/path/to/your/file .
```

### 5. Undo everything!

Once you're done it's probably good practice to disable the port forwarding and remote login.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that heroku is not designed for files to be uploaded manually like this, at least persistently. See https://help.heroku.com/K1PPS2WM/why-are-my-file-uploads-missing-deleted-from-the-application